# Understanding .xcconfig files in Xcode , why would we use it. I see one for debug, one for release.

Tags: ios, xcode

.xcconfig file are the config file for the debug and release with the specification in their file . Under the hood , in the Xcode, how it works in the lifecycle of compilation , is my query. When to use .xcconfig file. I have never used in my creation of framework, will I ever need to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't found much information about best practices, so I will answer from my opinion. `.xcconfig` files allows you to:

- reuse same configurations across different projects by just copying and assigning `.xcconfig` file
- build your project with different configurations by passing them to xcodebuid `xcodebuild -target <your_target_name> -xcconfig <your_configuration_file>.xcconfig`
- keep configurations separate from heavy Xcode project files, that makes tracking changes easier

In Xcode project you can set `.xcconfig`s for each configuration (Debug, Release) on project and on target level.

Xcode uses settings combined from .xcodeproj and assigned .xccofig file in following order:

1. macOS Default
2. Xcode project level
3. .xcconfig project level
4. .xcconfig target level
5. Xcode target level

Setting on each next level will override setting on previous level.

You can build your `.xccconfig` files hierarchy as you wish, that gives you a lot of flexibility. One of such hierarchies may look like follows:

```
- Warnings.xcconfig - keep warnings separate
   |- Base.xcconfig - settings common for debug and release; inherits Warnings.scconfig
      |- Debug.xcconfig - debug only settings; inherits Base.xcconfig
      |- Release.xcconfig - release only settings; inherits Base.xcconfig
- Target1.xcconfig - target specific settings, like Info.plist or product name
- Target2_Debug.xcconfig - target settings for debug
- Target2_Release.xcconfig - target settings for release
```

and assigned to project like on screenshot:
[image]

[The Unofficial Guide to xcconfig files](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html) may be useful for reading.